# how to restore the previous page on browser back button Click?

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to restore the previous page  on browser back button Click, i don't need reload the page, just restore it. I notice the url changed, but not the content? I am using master page.

Comment: This is so many times repeated question. Use SEARCH.

Comment: I would suggest reading through the existing answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=back+button+restore+previous+page

Answer (score 0):

If the page changes are you keeping state in a session? Look at this link for help with [Sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx). This will help to "restore" the content.

Also maybe onLoad may be worth having a look at

Ankou